# How does this ruby injection magic work?

Tags: ruby

I saw a ruby code snippet today.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].inject(:+)
```

`=> 28`

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].inject(:*)
```

`=> 5040`

The injection here is quite different from those I've seen before, like

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].inject {|sum, x| sum + x}
```

Please explain how does it work?

Comment: I don't know if there's a special name for it (if you wish to google for it), other than `Symbol#to_proc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no magic, symbol (method) is just one of the possible parameters. This is from the docs:

```
  # enum.inject(initial, sym) => obj
  # enum.inject(sym)          => obj
  # enum.inject(initial) {| memo, obj | block }  => obj
  # enum.inject          {| memo, obj | block }  => obj
```

Ours case is the second one.

You can also rewrite it with traditional block:

```
op = :+   #  parameter of inject call
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].inject {|sum, x| sum.send(op, x)} #  also returns 28
```

(to answer "how does it work" part)

Comment: Can't find information about symbol as parameters here, http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html. The doc is too old...

Comment: @Zifei  That's the link to version 1.8.6. Check http://ruby-doc.org/ for links to other versions, Core API section

Answer (score 3):

The :+ is a [symbol](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm) representing the addition message. Remember that Ruby has a Smalltalk style where just about every operation is performed by sending a message to an object.

As discussed in great detail [here](http://weblog.raganwald.com/2008/02/1100inject.html), `(1..100).inject(&:+)` is valid syntax in earlier versions where Rails has added the `to_proc` extension to Symbol.

The ability to pass just a symbol into inject was new in 1.9 and [backported into 1.8.7](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_8_7/NEWS).

Comment: And indeed this technique is known as "the (in)famous Symbol>>value: hack" (http://blog.3plus4.org/2007/03/27/selectors-as-blocks/) in the Smalltalk community: `(1..100) reduce: #+`

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [in the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Enumerable.html#M003050), `inject` can take a block (like you're familiar with) or a symbol that represents the name of a binary operator. It's a useful shorthand for already-defined ops.